# How to search specific string in JTable, not substring?

Tags: java, search, filter, jtable

I've made search for JTable. This code filters two columns. One column have two similar words, so filter    is not working. Here is my code:

```
    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> firstFiler = null;
    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> secondFilter = null;
    List<RowFilter<DefaultTableModel,Object>> filters = new      ArrayList<RowFilter<DefaultTableModel,Object>>();
    RowFilter<DefaultTableModel, Object> compoundRowFilter = null;

    try {
        secondFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter(this.filter, 12);
        firstFiler = RowFilter.regexFilter("AKTIVAN", 8);
        filters.add(firstFiler);
        filters.add(secondFilter);
        compoundRowFilter = RowFilter.andFilter(filters); 
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return;
    }   

    final TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>((DefaultTableModel) printTable.getModel());

    sorter.setRowFilter(compoundRowFilter);
    printTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

In column 8 I have words "NEAKTIVAN", "AKTIVAN". How to search just "AKTIVAN"?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
firstFiler = RowFilter.regexFilter("\bAKTIVAN\b", 8);
```

instead of

```
firstFiler = RowFilter.regexFilter("AKTIVAN", 8);
```

Comment: It's not working. When i try with string "NEAKTIVNO" it works.